# Android/java: synchronizing a local copy of instance

Tags: java, android, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the point of this synchronization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982649/whats-the-point-of-this-synchronization)

I'm using the BluetoothChat sample application to make my Bluetooth connection and there's this thing that's really bugging me at line 218:

```
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}
```

Why would one need to synchronize a local copy of the `ConnectedThread` instance, wouldn't synchronizing the `write` function do it (be it inside the `ConnectedThread` or the method above). I guess it's possible to call `write` multiple times from different threads at the same time, but I've always seen methods synced, not copies of instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not for `ConnectedThread` it for `mState` Synchronize should be used for both read and update.